# How to fix 'script should create dropdown options for each class 'list' '

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a script in a html form for adding options to a dropdown but it won't work. Why it's not working ?

I first tried to work with 'getElementByID' and the option got added to the dropdown after submit.
But i wanted the new added option in more than 1 dropdown so I changed the 'id' to 'class' and 'getElementByID' to 'getElementsbyClassName' and now it stopped working. Im unsure about the new added for loop because it worked before.

```js
            window.onload = function newoption(a) {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
                var i;
                for (i; i < x.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = a;
                    option.value = a;
                    x[i].add(option);
                }
            }
```

```html
    <form action="settings.html" method="GET" name="settings" onsubmit="newoption(add.value); return false;">
      <select class="list">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <input name="add" id="add" placeholder="new option">
      <button type="submit">add option</button>
    </form>
```

I expected to get a new drop down option but when I enter a text in the input field and press submit I do not get a new option.
Also should be the new entered option appear in all drop downs(not all dropdown's shown here! I have three where it should appear).

Comment: Hello thanks for your fast answer. I tried to edit my question and specify my problem. I hope it is clearer to understand now.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But I've still got a question. Do you want your form to submit or not? Because you call `newoption` on `onsubmit` but at the same time your return false right after the function call. Also you assigned `newoption` to `window.onload`. That confuses me. So do you want the form to submit (redirect to another page) or do you just want to add options to your dropdown?

Comment: Oh.. yes I want to submit on the same page - so just add options to dropdown! I thought the `window.onload` would be needed to load it on site refresh. And the `false` is for the else case ? I'm not sure how it works correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I got your requirements right.

1. You don't need `onload` -- in fact, you don't even need to submit the form (redirect to another page) if you just want to add options to your dropdown. I made that your form doesn't submit anymore. I achieved that by replacing `type="submit"` to `type="button"` inside your button. I also removed unnessecary code from your form.
2. You need to assign a value to your variable `i`. Otherwise your loop won't even start because the condition (`i < x.length`) will always be false.

   Either do `var i = 0;` or `for (var i = 0; ...)`.

   ```js
   function newoption(a) {
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
     var i = 0;
     for (i; i < x.length; i++) {
       var option = document.createElement("option");
       option.text = a;
       option.value = a;
       x[i].add(option);
     }
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <form action="settings.html" method="GET" name="settings">
     <select class="list">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
     </select>
     <input name="add" id="add" placeholder="new option">
     <button type="button" onclick="newoption()">add option</button>
   </form>
   ```

---

The value of your new option will be `undefined` all the time because your parameter `a` doesn't have any value.

If you want the text that got typed into your input field to be the text of your new option, you can do it by getting the value of your input when running your function:

`var newText = document.getElementById('add').value;`

All together:

```js
function newoption() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < x.length; i++) {
    var newText = document.getElementById('add').value;
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = newText;
    option.value = newText;
    x[i].add(option);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="settings.html" method="GET" name="settings">
  <select class="list">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <input name="add" id="add" placeholder="new option">
  <button type="button" onclick="newoption()">add option</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your detailed answer. This helped me a lot!

Comment: @anme98 Glad to help! :).